# Library for tree search for combinatorial optimization problems

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, generic-programming, a-star, tree-search

I notice that [some](https://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=1) [of](http://www.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=10753&pm=7478) the "hard" combinatorial problems I come across can be cast in terms of some type of tree search like alpha-beta pruning, or beam search, or a similar algorithm. However, programming them seems like repetitively coding the same things and it is also pretty easy to make mistakes. It seems to me there should be a library that implements these algorithms, and all I should be asked to write is

1. a coding for the solution, i.e., how to get a more specific solution from an incomplete solution. This will give the tree/graph structure.
2. Given a partial solution, how to get the maximum/minimum cost, and perhaps an estimate of the cost.
3. An Initial solution/partial solution.
4. Maybe some sort of a verification solution.

I am sorry I haven't given any specific code, but I think I have explained the problem. If I can write code for the functions described above, shouldn't I be able to run a number of tree/graph search algorithms easily? Is there any user friendly library/framework that supports this easily? I'd love it to be in Python or C/C++, but would be interested to hear any suggestions.

Edit: To be more precise, I am talking about informed tree search algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuego is an open-source monte-carlo tree search (as opposed to alpha-beta tree search) platform that can target 2-player full-information games (originally created to target Go).  It may even be more general than that.

http://fuego.sourceforge.net/

Edit:  I just learned that it also features an alpha-beta searcher.  Here is a recent paper:  http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~mmueller/ps/fuego-TCIAIG.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Expressing a problem without specifying the specific steps is a kind of [declarative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).

You talk about 'partial solutions'. Does this mean that the kind of problems you are considering have overlapping subproblems? If so, then it sounds like you're asking for a way to do general [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). All that really means is building a function through successive steps, solving simpler versions of the problem and then iterating. There are some nice examples in this [Mathematica journal article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v5i4/columns/wagner/42-51wagner.mj.pdf).

Have you considered [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)? It's not a framework, but the search algorithm, if you like, is built into the language. It's possible to write very general [constraint programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) solutions using something like Prolog as the basis. In Python there is the [python-constraint library](http://niemeyer.net/python-constraint), which is pretty nice - I've used it in the past.

Comment: Declarative Programming and dynamic programming don't really do informed tree searches, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @highBandWidth - Could you define what you mean by 'informed tree search'?

Comment: Sure, http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/cmsc421/chapter04a.pdf and Peter Norvigs book have good sections on informed search. Basically, if you know every vertex in a tree represents a solution, and related solutions are its children, can you use the current solutions to search for better solutions. A* and branch and bound algorithms come to mind.

Comment: +1 for useful information. Does declarative programming specify the search algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

**QuickGraph**

For anyone willing to go .Net, take a look at [the open source QuickGraph library](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) for all your graph/tree based processing. It neatly seperates all concepts related to graph-representation, -algorithms, -mutations and -presentation. It has lots of extension points so it should be able to support most graph-castable problems.

[EDIT] The set of algorithms supplied with QuickGraph does not include alpha-beta pruning or beam search at this moment, although its 'search' algorithm section includes 11 other methods that provide ample guidance for implementing your favorite traversal algorithm, and in time I would imagine it will support alpha-beta and beam.

**ad. 1**
It does satisfy your first criterion though, in that it is possible to insert a delegate function that returns several more specific solutions (i.e. neighboring nodes) based on an incomplete solution (i.e. current node). This is handled by [`DelegateImplicitGraph`](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55091#771190) (and variations) and is supposed to be memory efficient because it prevents having the whole search space in memory at once.
**ad. 2** Furthermore, the algorithms may take custom delegates such as max/min/expected cost hueristics (see [`AStarShortestPathAlgorithm`](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55091#377123)). This satisfies your second criterion.

In summary, QuickGraph helps you structure your problem, provides drop-in algorithms for various types of problems, and allows you to improve on it by supplying new algorithms.

Comment: Like BGL, I don't see any options to use it to search a solution space, this is more like graph traversal or already known graphs. Though I understand one can build on this, like one can on BGL or networkx.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has the [Boost Graph Libary (BGL)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html). The Boost Graph Library User's Guide has an [example](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/9780321601629/implicit-graphs-a-knight-tour/ch09lev1sec1) on the Knight's tour problem using implicit graphs.

Comment: BGL seems to have algorithms for traversing known graphs, not to search game trees or optimization decisions.

Comment: I just found BGL also has some support for implicit graphs and a-star.

Answer (score 1):

I found Peter Norvig's Python code for [informed and uninformed search](https://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/search.py) online. It has support for A-star search, and can be used to program for generic problems from what I can see. I wonder if it is fast enough or can be extended to beam search, branch and bound etc.